# How to write formula in google sheet using r or python?

Tags: python, r, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, googlesheets4

I'm trying to write an excel SUM formula to google sheet using R.
I want to sum for example values A1 + A2 and save the formula for that in A3.
**The problem is that it should be a formula because I have a big GDoc with many updates**

Using googlesheets4 it doesn't work because of leading apostrophe while pasting data (formula):

```
sheets_edit(
  gdoc_url,
  data = data.table('=sum(G6:G8)'),
  sheet = "wrk1",
  range = "A3",
  col_names = FALSE,
  reformat = TRUE
)
```

Do you have any solution for that in R or Python?
I know that in openxlsx it is possible but it works only for MS excel..

Comment: Short aswer: Use the Google Sheets API -> [tag:google-sheets-api].

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution.
In googlesheets4 R library is a function to formating text object to formula type.

```
dt[, fnct := paste0('=SUM(A2:A5)')]
dt$fnct <- sheets_formula(dt$fnct)
```

and then `sheets_edit()`